# Websphere not able to run application

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, websphere-8

I have installed a application on websphere, which makes soap call to a service.
While making soap call it throws following error

```
java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/axis/MessageContext, method=getMessage()Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage;, pc=0.
JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/axis/MessageContext, method=getMessage()Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage;, pc=0
```

I am using websphere 8.5.5.10 with websphere java version 1.7_64

Comment: Most probably you are embedding JAX-WS(axis) libraries in your application. Either remove these libraries or configure WAS to use third party JAX-WS engine as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html)

Comment: I configured the server to use third party JAX-WS but still I am getting the same issue,  does I need to make  change to the application as well on server?

Comment: Describe what did you change. Did you restart the server? Did you set `DisableIBMJAXWSEngine ` in JVM properties or MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: added the property in the server configuration and restarted the server but error still exists